# NetCDF Data Extraction and Interpolation for a Specific Region

Tags: interpolation, raster, netcdf, r-raster, resampling

I have a global NetCDF file form ISIMIP. I need a interpolate for a specific region. To do that I used a mask with the following code for a specific region. But the result I get is not exactly what I want. When I tried to do it without using a mask, I couldn't get any results. My specific location information is as follows: lon: 27.6, 42.8 (length=182) and lot: 40.8, 47.0 (length=125)

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
    # Load the mask file
ncmask <- nc_open("black_sea.mask.nc")
bsmask <- list(lon  = ncvar_get(ncmask, "lon"),
               lat  = ncvar_get(ncmask, "lat"),
               mask = ncvar_get(ncmask, "mask"))

new_dim <- list(lon  = bsmask$lon[,1],
                lat  = bsmask$lat[1,])

landseamask <- ncvar_get(ncmask, "mask")

nc_close(ncmask)

# Define ROI
ROI <- extent(min(new_dim$lon), max(new_dim$lon), min(new_dim$lat), max(new_dim$lat))

# Create the mask raster
mask.raster <- raster(t(landseamask), xmn=min(new_dim$lon), xmx=max(new_dim$lon), ymn=min(new_dim$lat), ymx=max(new_dim$lat))

# Load the dataset
fname <- "out.nc" 
dataset <- brick(fname)  

# Handle no-data values
r <- dataset[[1]]
# r[r < -300] <- NA
plot(r)

# Crop the raster to ROI
r.crop <- crop(r, ROI)

# Resample the mask to the crop raster
mask.raster.resampled <- resample(mask.raster, r.crop)

# Apply the mask before resampling
r.masked <- mask(r.crop, mask.raster.resampled)

# Define new grid
lon.pts <- seq(min(new_dim$lon), max(new_dim$lon), length.out = 182)
lat.pts <- seq(min(new_dim$lat), max(new_dim$lat), length.out = 125)

# Create a new raster from the coordinates
r.new <- raster(xmn=min(lon.pts), xmx=max(lon.pts), ymn=min(lat.pts), ymx=max(lat.pts), ncols=length(lon.pts), nrows=length(lat.pts))

# Resample the masked data to the new grid
r.resampled <- resample(r.masked, r.new, method="bilinear") # you may consider changing the method to "ngb" if necessary

# Resample the mask to the new grid
mask.raster.resampled <- resample(mask.raster, r.new, method="bilinear")

# Apply the resampled mask to the resampled data
r.masked.resampled <- mask(r.resampled, mask.raster.resampled)

# Plot the resampled raster
plot(r.masked.resampled)
```

And the result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvAzm.png)